# Gradle-Publish -- no pom.xml file being created

Tags: maven, gradle, publish

I'm trying to publish a library to an AWS S3 Maven repository using [this](https://medium.com/@porten/publishing-android-library-artifacts-to-amazon-s3-buckets-8db4231e844f) guide. After finally getting it to upload the artifacts to the S3 bucket without error, I made it a dependency of a new project per the guide.

When I tried to build the new project, an error occurred stating that it couldn't find the first of my library's dependencies. Sure enough, there was no pom.xml file generated that would have included that dependency (and others).

Not knowing a lot about how program Gradle tasks, I think the problem is within the pom.withXml {} portion of the script. Or the problem may occur before that since there's not even an empty pom.xml file.

Here is the entire script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

// update these next lines to fit your submodule
group = 'com.myproject'
version = '1.0'

// Add sources as an artifact
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier "source"
}

// Loop over all variants
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        // This creates a publication for each variant
        publishing.publications.create(variant.name, MavenPublication) {
            // The sources artifact from earlier
            artifact sourceJar

            // Variant dependent artifact, e.g. release, debug
            artifact source: output.outputFile, classifier: output.name

            // Go through all the dependencies for each variant and add them to the POM
            // file as dependencies
            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                // Filter out anything that's not an external dependency. You shouldn't
                // be publishing artifacts that depend on local (e.g. project) dependencies,
                // but who knows...
                configurations.getByName(variant.name + "CompileClasspath").allDependencies
                        .findAll { it instanceof ExternalDependency }
                        .each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')

                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Ensure that the publish task depends on assembly
tasks.all { task ->
    if (task instanceof AbstractPublishToMaven) {
        task.dependsOn assemble
    }
}

// Configure the destination repository with
// S3 URL and access credentials
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "s3://sdk.myproject.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
                secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas about what's going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: please include the whole section around publication, including which plugin you applied.

Comment: @LouisJacomet I included the entire script. Thanks.